# Change Attribute of All Tags

Tags: javascript

I want to change the `disabled` property of all `<input>` tag in a page. There are several. And I have done it with ID easily, and:

```
document.getElementsByTagName("INPUT")[0].disabled = false;
```

Works. But I can't find how to do it for *all* of the input tags?
I have tried:

```
document.getElementsByTagName("INPUT").disabled = false;
```

And:

```
var list =  document.getElementsByTagName("INPUT")[0].disabled = false;
list.getElementsByTagName("INPUT").disabled = false;
```

How can I accomplish that? Is there a way of doing a `foreach` in a list of tags?

Comment: You need to loop over all inputs and set every single one to disabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use `document.querySelectorAll` and then iterate over elements.

For example:

```
[].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('input'), el => {
  /* your code */
})
```

Comment: What does `querySelectorAll` change in regard to the problem?

Comment: I've edited my answer using `forEach`. `querySelectorAll` is for example.

Comment: @sergei in this code, how will I reference the current input in the foreach to change it's atribute?

Comment: It is `el` in a callback function.
@William

Answer (score 0):

Create array of input then loop with for changing each one display property

```
var list =  document.getElementsByTagName("INPUT");
for(var i =0; i<list.length;i++)
{
    list[i].disable=false;
}
```